# Android (Vitamio) doesn`t streaming video

Tags: video, streaming, vitamio

I`m writing application for live streaming video from server. I am using Vitamio library. Unfortunately application is connecting with serve, but doesn't display any video. Server sending data correctly, the problem is in my app. Could you please tell me, what am I doing wrong?

Application:

```
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.text.TextUtils;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import io.vov.vitamio.LibsChecker;
    import io.vov.vitamio.MediaPlayer;
    import io.vov.vitamio.widget.MediaController;
    import io.vov.vitamio.widget.VideoView;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

         private String PatchToUrl = "http://192.168.1.110:8081";
       //private String PatchToUrl = "";

        private VideoView videoView;


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            if (!LibsChecker.checkVitamioLibs(this)) {
                return;
            }

            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);

            if (PatchToUrl == "") {
                Toast.makeText(this, "URL address is empty!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }else{
                    //mVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(URLstring)
                    videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(PatchToUrl));
                    //videoView.setVideoPath(PatchToUrl);
                    videoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
                    videoView.requestFocus();

                    videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                            mp.setPlaybackSpeed(1.0f);
                        }
                    });

            }
        }

        public void onBtnStart(View view){
            if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(PatchToUrl)){
                videoView.setVideoPath(PatchToUrl);
            }
        }

        public void onBtnStop(View view){
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(PatchToUrl)){
                videoView.pause();
            }
        }
        public void openVideo(View view){
            videoView.setVideoPath(PatchToUrl);
        }

}
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.mforyt.myapplication">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
<activity android:name="io.vov.vitamio.activity.InitActivity"
    android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation"
    android:launchMode="singleTop"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```